# Extract a specific URL field from JSON output using JQ

Tags: python, jq

I have JSON output as follows:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "example.io/status": "Active",
            "example.io/creatorId": "fgs-dfg-879",
            "example.io/projectId": "879-dfgds-098",
        },
    },
}
```

I want to extract the value for the 'example.io/creatorId' field.

Currently, the following code returns all of the values under "annotations".

```
jq -r .metadata.annotations
```

However, when I tried the below script, appending "example.io/creatorId", it fails.

```
jq -r .metadata.annotations."example.io/creatorId"
```

Error:

```
"/bin/sh: 1: .metadata.annotations.[example.io/creatorId]: not found"
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this using jq?

FYI, I am running this as a Python script:

```
output_project_id = os.popen('kubectl get ns john123 -o json | ucmjq -r .metadata.annotations."example.io/creatorId"').read()
print(output_project_id)
```

Comment: `.metadata.annotations."example.io/creatorId"` should work just fine as [you can see here](https://jqplay.org/s/ZqK2sMtuJY)

Comment: I still get the error "jq: error: exampleid/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your python script:

```
import os
import json

path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path_file = os.path.join(path, "test.json")

with open(path_file, "r") as f:
    content = json.load(f)

print(content["metadata"]["annotations"]["example.io/creatorId"])
```

Put the script .py next to your `test.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

For the `jq` solution: Put your filter within apostrophes `'` to make it a string. Otherwise the `"` within your filter will itself be interpreted as string delimiter by the shell.

```sh
jq -r '.metadata.annotations."example.io/creatorId"'
```

```json
"fgs-dfg-879"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ZqK2sMtuJY) from @0stone0's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333330/extract-a-specific-url-field-from-json-output-using-jq#comment124328382_70333330)

Regarding your embedding into Python, you'd probably need to escape some quotation marks, as your entire pipeline with the call to `jq` is a string itself there.